# What is the source of Higgs field?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, higgs

Could you please explain me this question. 
As we know that every field has a source like electric field has electric charge and magnetic field has magnet etc. So what is the source of the Higgs field?

Comment: The sources for the Higgs field are the rest of fields in the Standard Model, such as the electron field, the $Z$ field, etc.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

The Higgs  particle is an elementary particle in the [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) of particle physics

[image]

All elementary particles have a meaning in the quantum mechanical framework, n[ot the classical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory#Classical_and_quantum_fields) that you are discussing.

In quantum field theory, every particle in the table above is a quantized field which covers all spacetime. Creation and annihilation operators define the sources , for example a creation operator creates an electron, acting on the electron field,  or a Higgs particle creation operator acting on the Higgs field creates a Higgs meson.

Answer (score -2):

Good question. The Lagrangian  of the Standard Model of physics is constructed in such a way that the standard answer to your question is: the Higgs field itself. This is because it contains a huge self-interaction term $\lambda\phi^4$ that causes the ground state of the Higgs to correspond to a constant nonzero value. However, the existence of such a term has not yet been established experimentally and there are other possible explanations for the Higgs vacuum expectation value (which definitely IS established) that do not involve self-interaction.